# website looks great on minimized browser, but trashy on iPad

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am working on a [website](http://calebbertrand.github.io) with pure html5 and css3. If you view it on a computer browser, it looks fine, even if you resize it to be almost as small as an iPhone or Tablet. However, on an actual iPad, the starting screen looks trashy. This is my css for the logo and the scroll down button, which are mainly the ones giving me trouble:

```
#main-name {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #111;
  margin: auto;
  top: -65vh;
  width: 12%;
  min-width: 135px;
  height: 170px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: solid rgb(50, 50, 50) 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Orbitron", "sans-serif";
  z-index: 1;
}
#scroll-down {
  position: relative;
  width: 83px;
  height: 83px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  top: -52vh;
  margin-bottom: -260px;
  background-image: url("imgs/down-arrow.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 4px 10px;
  opacity: 0.65;
  font-family: "Orbitron", "sans-serif";
  z-index: 1;
}
#scroll-down:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: opacity;
  animation-duration: 1.2s;
}
@media only screen and (max-height: 500px) {
    /* For mobile phones: */
    #main-name {
      top: -75vh;
    }
    #scroll-down {
      top: -70vh;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please describe the issue in detail? I've had a little play with the device emulator in Chrome and have seen some issues in there that surface when virtually rotating the device. Are these the issues that you are talking about?

Comment: I don't have an emulator right now, but I do have an iPad. If it is not in landscape mode, then the logo and button appear too far up, and not centered with the background. Hope that helps

Comment: Ok. It looks like there are some position and size values being changed on the canvas, the logo and the scroll down button via JavaScript. These appear to be related to the relative position of the logo and scroll down button. If it were me, I'd absolutely position those last 2 elements using a calculation in the css. I'd also give the canvas a height and width of 100vh/100vw rather than altering the size on window resize, which is what appears to be happening now. I'm not at my PC at the moment, but I'll post an answer with a fiddle later. I hope this helps for now.

Comment: Well, the reason I didn't use absolute positioning is because then I would not be able to use margin: auto to help keep them it centered. I tinkered with the left and right values for a while, but it didn't stay centered when I resized the browser. Any suggestions on centering an absolute element?

Comment: As for the javascript, I am using p5's resize function to make sure the canvas is the correct size when the window is resized. I tried using css to handle it, but something about p5 keeps the canvas the same size.

Comment: You could try using left: calc(50vw - ([width of element] / 2)) and height: calc(50vh - ([height of element] / 2)).